# Getting LatLng error to get direction?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, geocoding, direction

I try to get direction my current location and which i like to interest place
and i used [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJguXeAk9OU) 
tutorial i have two button Marker and Direction when i click marker button my application will crush

**My Main Java Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText addressEditText, finalAddressEditText;
LatLng addressPos, finalAddressPos;
Marker addressMarker;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
//static final LatLng pos = new LatLng(40, -79);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.startAddresseditText);
    finalAddressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalAddresseditText);

    try {
        if (googleMap==null){
            googleMap =((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
       // Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title("Hamel"));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void showAddressMarker(View view) {
    String newAddress = addressEditText.getText().toString();

    if (newAddress!=null) {
        new PlaceAMarker().execute(newAddress);
    }
}
public void getDirection(View view) {
    String startingAddress = addressEditText.getText().toString();
    String finalAddress = finalAddressEditText.getText().toString();
    if ((startingAddress.equals("")) || (finalAddress.equals(""))) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Enter a Starting & Ending Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        new GetDirection().execute(startingAddress, finalAddress);
    }
}
class GetDirection extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String startAddress = params[0];
        startAddress = startAddress.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        getLatLng(startAddress, false);
        String endingAddress = params[1];
        endingAddress = endingAddress.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        getLatLng(endingAddress,true);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        String geoUriString ="http://maps.google.com/maps?addr="+
                addressPos.latitude +","+
                addressPos.longitude+"&daddr="+
                finalAddressPos.latitude+","+
                finalAddressPos.longitude;

        Intent mapcall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUriString));
        startActivity(mapcall);
    }
}
class PlaceAMarker extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String startAddress = params[0];
        startAddress = startAddress.replaceAll(" ","%20");

        getLatLng(startAddress,false);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        addressMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(addressPos).title("Address"));
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}

protected void getLatLng(String address, boolean setDestination){
    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+
            address +"&sensor=false";
    HttpGet httpGet= new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int byteData;
        while ((byteData = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char)byteData);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    double lat =0.0, lng=0.0;
    JSONObject jsonObject;

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

        lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("result")).getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                .getDouble("lng");

        lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("result")).getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                .getDouble("lat");
        if (setDestination) {
            finalAddressPos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        } else {
            addressPos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Error in LogCat**

```
02-20 13:29:43.578  11232-11232/googlemap.com E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no position in marker options
        at com.google.k.a.cl.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.al.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addMarker(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
        at googlemap.com.MainActivity$PlaceAMarker.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:122)
        at googlemap.com.MainActivity$PlaceAMarker.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:108)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: *when i click marker button my application will crush* : probably showing some log in logcat. post it with question

Comment: logcat! logcat! gimme logcat!

Comment: i update logcat errors

Comment: @HamelRaj: What string you are getting in stringBuilder.toString() ?